# Options to animate IT diagrams

Tags: charts, diagram, flowchart

I really want to have one software that will allow me to animate my diagrams (mostly on IT) to have something like [this](https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D22AQEw84VdHIap2Q/feedshare-shrink_2048_1536/0/1690691059332?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=5NDt4xV7sbvbz6kytnEUyMHOn3GGUHVm9Z3at2yvd0Q) or [this one](https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E22AQEBB4A23pnvRw/feedshare-shrink_2048_1536/0/1678774884083?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=RIRgisILsf1KNrE3RPh3d2c5H3h0XRYSDsO3Gm0tejI), or in the style of ByteByteGo.

Oh, and I already know Drawi.io has the "animate" option...
Also, I'm taking any links to video or articles/courses that explain how to animate (IT) diagrams in a professional way. I know that PowerPoint has animation features, but I haven't yet looked into how I can use them for my goal. Most videos I find are about circles animations and I'm more interested in flow animations, like data flow or networking requests flows, etc.